# Why does PowerShell exit unexpected on "Get-Credentials"?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, credentials

I am running a PowerShell gui script, I need to hide away the batch script which loads it. (This makes it easier for my team to load it.)

Batch script:

```
@ECHO OFF
pushd "NETWORK SHARE"
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -WindowStyle hidden -NoProfile -file .\FileName.ps1
popd
```

I have gotten it to allow popups to come in by using:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
```

But the following line causes the PowerShell script to freeze & exit unexpected.

```
$mycredentials = Get-Credential # This is necessary as some people may not use their admin accounts to login
```

Some of my team members do not login with their administrator accounts and use their standard accounts to sign in and do things. Some sign in with their administrator accounts to do things.

Comment: Sorry to say I don't think there is enough information to answer your questions.  I'm a little confused about why you would need to add the assemblies unless you are drawing both winform and wpf UI elements but without showing your additional code I can't tell if this is needed or not.  The rest of your code is syntactically correct so there would be no reason it would freeze or crash.  What version of PowerShell/Windows are you using?  What happens when you run it as WindowStyle Normal.  Are there any visible errors?

Comment: Hi Paul,

Due to security reasons I cannot provide the remainder of the code. It is loading a GUI script and to get the alert boxes to popup it needed the AssemblyTypes I tried one then the other, but they both came up with errors so I added both and boom. There's the alert boxes.

Doing -WindowStyle normal causes it to freeze & crash

`Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles() #Enable the GUI Menu`

Comment: All the information that you've given is well written and shouldn't crash.  Maybe take all the code you've posted here without anything else and see if that crashes.  If it doesn't, its another part of your code.  If it does, however, it may be OS/.NET corruption or a misconfiguration.

Comment: Hi Paul,

All other code runs clean, the minute it hits Credentials it crashes out. my work around for the time being is to keep up the batch script whilst the PS script runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I've done is wrote the following code and thrown it into a little bat file to test out the core stuff you are trying to achieve.

```
 powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -windowstyle hidden -noprofile -command "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework;get-credential;start-sleep 10"
```

If you have `-windowstyle hidden` the script will fail because `Get-Credential` will not trigger a pop up asking for your credentials and just exit (Or maybe it runs but has no credentials).

Once you remove `-windowstyle hidden` the script will run, create the pop up to grab credentials then hang for 10 seconds before closing.

I also threw in `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()` but that didn't change anything.

Unless you provide a username and password to `Get-Credential` it will create a pop up. Since you insist on it being hidden, then you will need to manually prompt the user for their Username and Password, or use an extra account with limited permissions. An alternative might be to use a windows form pop up to prompt for a username and password, then use those to generate the credentials rather than `Get-Credential`

Without more information on your code and what you are trying to achieve with the credentials its impossible to help you anymore. You can always clean your code to remove references to users, servers and other sensitive information. If you want proper help, you need to be willing to share what you have done.

Comment: `-ExecutionPolicy` is not used for PowerShell `-Command`s, only for PowerShell script `-File`s.